# Table Row Start Position causing Misalignment

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have the following table (contents removed) which I constructed from multiple separate copy and paste operations from a different Word file:
[image]

The option that's causing the table to misalign is the row's individual "Indent from Left" property, which AFAIK MS Word doesn't allow you to adjust manually, and only through VBA macros.

How do you align the table row utilizing a VBA macro? Assuming this needs to done on individual rows and not on the a property of the whole table, it probably won't work if there are vertical merges present. Is there a way to align the table without first manually unmerging all vertical/horizontal merges within the table. See example table below:
[image]

Lastly, I know I could recreate the table by 1) creating a new blank table with the same number of rows and columns and 2) copy/pasting the contents of my misaligned table into the blank table. I know this is a option, but i'm looking for an alternate option that's not so manual as again I'm working with a huge set of tables, and many times these tables can also be irregular and have vertical/horizontal merges. It would just be painful recreating them this way.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Part 1:

> Question: The option that's causing the table to misalign is the row's individual "Intent from Left" property, which AFAIK MS Word doesn't allow you to adjust manually, and only through VBA macros.

> Asnwer: You can manually adjust "Indent from Left".

### [image]

- Part 2:

Using `SetLeftIndent` to align a table, it will set the left indent for all rows in the table. The distance (`sngIndent`) is in points. I have tested the code with merged cells.

```
Sub AlignTable()
    Dim oTab As Table
    Dim sngIndent As Single
    sngIndent = 15
    For Each oTab In ActiveDocument.Tables
        oTab.Rows.SetLeftIndent LeftIndent:=sngIndent, _
            RulerStyle:=wdAdjustNone
    Next
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Appreciate the help! Unfortunately my hunch about it being SetLeftIndent isn't correct, and it looks like that isn't what's causing the alignment issue =( I went ahead and updated my post, know anything I might be able to try?

Comment: Actually I tried again, and apparently it doesn't fix the alignment when I do oTab.Rows, but when iterated through the Rows it did align the entire table: oTab.Rows(i).SetLeftIndent. Problem now is that I have cells that are either vertically or horizontally merged, and without fixing those I can't actually iterate through the rows of the table without getting the error "Cannot access individual rows in this collection because the table has vertically merged cells." Problem is I was trying to fix the alignment in the first place so that I can unmerge everything. =(

Comment: @DCUnited I’ve uploaded a screenshot showing a sample table where I tried to simulate your case. It would be useful if you could provide a screenshot showing "cells that are either vertically or horizontally merged".

Comment: I did a more comprehensive update to my original post. In the first example table, when I perform a oTab.Rows.SetLeftIndent, my version of MS Word only aligns the last row, doesn't align the row 2 that is also offset. Although, as I indicated, by iterating through the rows with oTab.Rows(i).setLeftIndent it did align all the rows. But some of my tables have vertical merges, which I've also added an example. This prevents the approach with using setLeftIndent on individual rows as individual rows cannot be selected for tables with vertical merges.

Comment: @DCUnited I updated my post to answer your questions.